# Get URL of XML page from within XSL

Tags: xslt

How do I get the URL of the XML page from within the XSL, if it is not defined in the XML?

Comment: There is no question stated and the matter discussed does not truly relate to XSLT. I have voted to CLOSE this question.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: Ok, I've explicitly added my question and added an XSL tag... XSL or XSLT - I'm not sure of the difference.

Comment: XSLT and XSL are one in the same. The problem is you haven't defined much of a problem at all. I think the issue you're having is an ill-defined problem domain.

Comment: @Jweede: So there is no way to get the URL of the XML page from within the XSL?

Comment: @fudgey: Please, edit the question and just put the single sentence from your last comment to @Jweede.

Comment: Good edit. I now reversed my downvote.

Comment: No, still not a question. Is this XSL in a browser, or running from some API? Which XML page is it talking about?

Comment: @bmargulies: if you really want to know the full question for this question that has already been sufficiently answered then look at my edit history - I chopped all of that extra stuff out as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT doesn't have a mechanism in and of itself to fetch the URL which it was retrieved from. However You could try using Javascript to pass the URL as a parameter to the stylesheet. Much like what [this guy](http://www.jwc3.net/2008/05/how-to-get-url-in-xsl.html) does.

Comment: Thanks for the response JWeede, but I'm a complete noob when it comes to XSLT and I have no idea where the `ParameterBinding` variables should be located. I get an error if I add them to my XSL, does it go somewhere else?

Comment: basically his suggestion is to grab the URL information with javascript and then pass it into XSLT as a parameter. If you have access to manipulate the incoming XML to XSLT this is an option as well.

Answer (score 2):

Within an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet you may be able to use the standard XPath 2.x functions **[base-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-base-uri)** and **[document-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-document-uri)**

Comment: Sadly, only XSLT 1.0 is available to me